# Undo modifications to constructor's scope on error

Tags: javascript, constructor, scope

I have a constructor that I created which has a method which modifies a bunch of local variables.  My problem is that the method may throw some error, so when an error occurs I want to restore the scope to it's previous state.  Obviously I could create a bunch of temporary variables and then just assign those to the variables that the constructor actually uses, but that's not really an optimal solution.  I want to know if there is any way I can modify the variables from the method and restore them to the state they were before the method was called in the case of an error.

Comment: So you want to back up some variables, but storing the original values is 'not optimal'. How do you propose to restore, if you haven't backed up in the first place?

Comment: "but that's not really an optimal solution". Do you mean it's not optimal because *you* have to do the unwinding of the stack? If so, don't use JavaScript (or most languages for that matter). If you're writing for a browser, feel free to use one of the many browser-side `call/cc` implementing languages that don't exist. Otherwise just use LISP.

Comment: Good case for Memento pattern :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than the global scope, there's no real way to interact with scopes in JavaScript.  You can create objects, that act as scopes, though.

## [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/yvqah)

```
function Scope(data){
  this.data = data;
  this.stages = [];
  this.save(data);
}

Scope.prototype.save = function(){
  var oldData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data));
  this.stages.push(oldData);
}

Scope.prototype.undo = function(){
  var lastData = this.stages.pop();
  this.data = lastData;
}
```

We can then create a scope with some data.

```
var scope = new Scope({name: "John"});
```

Now, we have a strange function with highly preferental treatment for people named Paul.

```
function myFunction(data) {
  if (data.name === "John") {
    data.name = "Paul";
    throw new Error("I don't like John!");
  }
}
```

We can then call our function in a try/catch.

```
try {
  myFunction(scope.data);
}
catch (e) {
  // scope.data is {name: "Paul"}
  scope.undo();
  // scope.data is {name: "John"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use **stack**,

eg.

```
var Stack = new Array();

doModification(10,'');

function doModification(A,B){
   Stack.push(A);
   Stack.push(B);

   // after modifying,
   try{
     A= 10; 
     if(B == 0) throw new Error("Divide by Zero Exception.");
     B= A/B;
   }
   catch(e){
     // if exception then restore original vars
     B = Stack.pop();
     A = Stack.pop();
     alert(e.description);
   }

   // else if error doesn't come then, clear the stack
   Stack = [];

}
```

Comment: Just so you know, `10/0` doesn't throw an error.  It [results in `Infinity`](http://jsfiddle.net/4T5EJ/).

Comment: @fakeRainBrigand - it will throw - "divide by zero exception"

Comment: In some languages, but not JavaScript, except maybe on old browsers.  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4T5EJ/).  Firefox and Chrome give Infinity.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - yes you are right, I have corrected the example now, plz check.

Comment: Looks good.  It'll work as long as no objects or arrays are passed in (which they probably won't be in most situations).